# Model car queueing with two gates

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, queueing-theory

Say a school has two gates at which parents can pick up their kids. One gate is only for primary school students and the other is only for secondary school students. The school has a primary school to secondary school population ratio of $p:s$.

[image]

Now, say I have cars queueing behind the two gates, with each cars assigned to be whether for picking up primary school students or secondary school students based on the population ratio (labeled "p" and "s" in the image). Each car takes $w$ seconds to pick up their kids (equal time at both primary gate and secondary gate). And $s$ cars have to wait and queue behind $p$ cars to pick up their kids.

I would like to model this queueing system and find out after time $t$, what is the total number of students that are picked up from the school.

Should I use the Poisson process? How should I approach this problem? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How long does it take to pick up a student at P and S? Do $s$ cars wait if there is a $p$ parent picking up a student? One problem is that the state of the system is not just the length of the queue, but it's exact composition (like you illustrate). You could set up the balance equations for steady state, assuming e.g. Poisson arrivals for $s$ and $p$, and exponentially distributed pick-up times at S and P, but it won't be a classic queue.

Comment: @vonbrand okay! so let's say it takes $w$ seconds to pick up a student at P and S (equal time at both gates). And yes, $s$ cars have to wait for $p$ parent to pick up their kids. I will add these information to my question. Regarding the balance equation, can you give me some pointers on how I can approach the problem and construct the balance equations assuming Poisson arrivals? Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand, but if the time for pickup is equal and s cars have to wait for p cars (p cars also have to wait for s cars anyway), then there is no practical difference between s cars and p cars, so the total time is just number of students times average pickup time, no?

Comment: Ah ok you mean an s car has to wait if it's behind a p car. But if a p car is behind a s car, they can both go forward at the same time to their respective gate, but in all other cases they have to wait time w. So you only have to find the number of sp pairs.

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen Thank you for the comment!. Yes, there would be extra time if a s car is after a p car. Right now I am struggling modeling the scenario using the Poisson process, so I am not entirely sure how to incorporate that into the model.

Comment: I haven't really thought this through, but is Poisson suitable, considering the cars are not independent events but the total number of p and s are fixed? I wonder if there is an easier way that you just have to calculate expected number m of sp pairs in a sequence of n cars, which is a bit of combinatorics. Then the time is (n-m)w, so you have time as function of car numbers which you invert to get cars as function of time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The reason I suggest looking for sp pairs is that they can move at the same time to their gates, so they essentially need one time step for two cars whereas otherwise it's one time step per car. In your image, the last two cars can pick up their kids at the same time as s is beyond the p gate so the last car doesn't have to wait.

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen thank you for the comment! Yes, I think in that sense maybe the problem can be solved using combinatorics. However, I also want to model the random event of the arrivals of cars. Perhaps I should incorporate both combinatorics and the Poisson model?

Comment: And say instead of fixed number p and s, maybe the number of cars in the problem don't need to be finite. They keep coming based of the ratio of p:s.

Comment: Can you clarify if the total number of students if fixed? Any real school has a certain known number of students, and generally fairly small (dozens or hundreds). So if more primary students arrive early, you get more secondary later, and it stops when everybody is there. If you don't assume this, a better example might be a petrol station with a petrol and a diesel pump where any number of petrol and diesel cars can arrive with a known probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand correctly your problem - please add remarks if needed

let's say that each $w$ time you will have one of following events:

1. car $p$ waits for student and there is no $s$ car in front- so one car is waiting
2. $s$ car is waiting and behind him is car $s$ so also one car is waiting
3. there was two cars in queue $p$ and $s$ so two cars are waiting
   now let's count probability that we will have pair $ps$ in sequence

in general it's **markov process** from here we will create transition matrix $m$, you can derive $p(S)\ p(P)\ p(PS)$ (here it will be difficult) and assign weights $1\ 1\ 2$ and compute $E(X)$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
  \text{from\to} & P & SS & PS \\ 
\hline
   P & \frac{p}{p+s} & \frac{s^2}{(p+s)^2} & \frac{sp}{(p+s)^2} \\
\hline
   SS & 0 & \frac{s}{p+s} & \frac{p}{p+s} \\
\hline
   PS & \frac{p}{p+s} & \frac{s^2}{(p+s)^2} & \frac{sp}{(p+s)^2} \\ 
\hline
\end{array}

now create vector initial vector $v_1 = (\frac{p}{p+s}, \frac{s^2}{(p+s)^2}, \frac{sp}{(p+s)^2})$ (fill exact values s and p into these structures)
and count in for loop $v_{n+1} = v_n*m$
at each step vector $v$ will have probabilities of events $(p(P), p(SS), p(PS))$ and you can calculate $EX_n = (1,1,2) * v_n$ which will be expected value of students picked up at step $n$

````
#given  m, v, n
sum_x = 0
for i in range(n):
  v = v * m
  sum_x += [1,1,2] * v.T
return sum_x

```
````

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution! I am just curious on why markov process is applicable here. I understand that in markov proceess an event is depent upon the previous event, but the arrival of the cars are not dependent upon any previous events. Can this scenario also be modeled using the Poisson process?

Comment: @StevenOh I assumed that you have endless stream of cars and you would like to know how quick this stream will proceed, in general you could model **car arrival times** with Poisson process (like calls in call center, although amount of calls in call center is much more uniform throughout the day than car arrivals to school), but there are would be two approaches: 1. cars arrive independently and "type" is chosen at random, or two poisson processes with given intensities $p$ and $s$, if you would give more details of your system I could give more ideas

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughtful answer! I think the first approach might work better with what I have been thinking. So, the cars arrive independently and their type is decided by a binomial probability. Can you give me more ideas regarding this? Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: @StevenOh here is link to paper that solves easier problem with two spots with no distinction https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijsa/2012/145867/, also systems that you want to model are M/M/c queues https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/c_queue, but your system looks more complicated than these in links, probably there is something that fits your needs. This looks most promising https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markovian_arrival_process

Comment: thank you so much for the resources. I have been reading them and they are super helpful. Lastly, do you think it would also be an option to model my problem in a case-by-case manner. So for each cases of the combination between car $p$ and car &s& (eg. ps, sp, pp, ss), I model using a poisson process, and then later I sum these up somehow. Again, thank you for your input.